# Remove formats options from tinemce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I use tinymce editor and i have this code:

```
tinymce.init({

    selector: ".edytor"

});
```

I want to remove such options from editor:

- Headings (all)
- Inline (all)
- Blocks (to be only Paragraph)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure tinymce to only allow paragraphs:

```
forced_root_block: 'p',

valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style],"
+ "a[name|href|target|title|alt],"
+ "#p,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|unselectable],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u,"
+ "-span[data-mce-type],hr",

valid_child_elements : "body[p,ol,ul]"
+ ",p[a|span|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|hr|#text]"
+ ",span[a|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|#text]"
+ ",a[span|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|#text]"
+ ",b[span|a|i|u|sup|sub|img|#text]"
+ ",i[span|a|b|u|sup|sub|img|#text]"
+ ",sup[span|a|i|b|u|sub|img|#text]"
+ ",sub[span|a|i|b|u|sup|img|#text]"
+ ",li[span|a|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|ol|ul|#text]"
+ ",ol[li]"
+ ",ul[li]",
```

Plus you will need to overwrite the default tinymce formats.
Have a look at this tinymce documentation page to find out more: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:formats